# Errors compiling very simple boost::spirit grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've been working through the tutorials to Boost::Spirit and I'm trying to compile a super simple parser for adding numbers together, roughly based on the [MiniXML example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html) in the docs. I'm having trouble compiling in Xcode 5.1.1.

I've reduced it and found that even the definition of the grammar won't compile. Here is its current state:

Syntax.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


template <typename Iterator>
struct ExpressionGrammer : qi::grammar<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> addsub;

    ExpressionGrammer()
    : ExpressionGrammer::base_type(expression)
    {
        using qi::lit;

        addsub = (expression >> '+' >> expression)[_val = _1 + _2];     
        expression = (addsub | qi::double_)[_val = _1];
    }
};
```

Syntax.cpp:

```
#include "Syntax.h"

// Nothing else
```

The errors are long and detailed but uninformative starting with a parse issue 'Declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition'. The first section I'll paste here. (Note the line numbers don't match as I've omitted commented out code)

```
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.h:12:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:19:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/proto.hpp:12:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/core.hpp:21:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/fusion.hpp:22:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/include/intrinsic.hpp:10:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/back.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/end.hpp:17:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/detail/segmented_end.hpp:10:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/detail/segmented_end_impl.hpp:14:
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/container/list/cons_fwd.hpp:13:5: error: declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition
    struct nil;
    ^
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/container/list/cons_fwd.hpp:13:5: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
    struct nil;
    ^~~~~~
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/container/list/cons_fwd.hpp:15:44: error: expected a type
    template <typename Car, typename Cdr = nil>
                                           ^
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/SpiritTest_Prefix.pch:8:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/AppBasic.h:27:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/App.h:27:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/Renderer.h:32:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:68:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/MacTypes.h:90:17: note: expanded from macro 'nil'
    #define nil NULL
                ^
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/SpiritTest_Prefix.pch:6:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/Cinder.h:92:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/chrono:280:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:203:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/cstddef:44:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include/stddef.h:72:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#    define NULL __null
                 ^
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.h:12:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:19:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/proto.hpp:12:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/core.hpp:21:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/fusion.hpp:22:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/include/intrinsic.hpp:10:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/back.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/end.hpp:17:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/detail/segmented_end.hpp:10:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/detail/segmented_end_impl.hpp:14:
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/container/list/cons_fwd.hpp:15:44: error: expected ',' or '>' in template-parameter-list
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/SpiritTest_Prefix.pch:8:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/AppBasic.h:27:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/App.h:27:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/Renderer.h:32:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:68:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/MacTypes.h:90:17: note: expanded from macro 'nil'
    #define nil NULL
                ^
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/SpiritTest_Prefix.pch:6:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/Cinder.h:92:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/chrono:280:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:203:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/cstddef:44:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include/stddef.h:72:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#    define NULL __null
                 ^
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.h:12:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:14:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:19:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/proto.hpp:12:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/core.hpp:21:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/proto/fusion.hpp:22:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/include/intrinsic.hpp:10:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/back.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/end.hpp:17:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/detail/segmented_end.hpp:11:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/iterator/segmented_iterator.hpp:10:
In file included from ../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/iterator/detail/segmented_iterator.hpp:18:
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/iterator/detail/segmented_equal_to.hpp:16:5: error: declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition
    struct nil;
    ^
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/iterator/detail/segmented_equal_to.hpp:16:5: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
    struct nil;
    ^~~~~~
../../../Cinder/boost/boost/fusion/iterator/detail/segmented_equal_to.hpp:35:43: error: expected unqualified-id
        struct segmented_equal_to<fusion::nil, fusion::nil>
                                          ^
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/Syntax.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/SpiritTest_Prefix.pch:8:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/AppBasic.h:27:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/App.h:27:
In file included from /Users/timmb/Documents/Programming/demos/SpiritTest/xcode/../../../Cinder/include/cinder/app/Renderer.h:32:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:68:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/MacTypes.h:90:17: note: expanded from macro 'nil'
    #define nil NULL
```

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

(Incidentally, I'm using Boost 1.53 due to an external library requirement.)

Comment: The error dump you showed seems to indicate that you have an evil define `#define nil NULL` which will **wreak havoc** when included before any the boost headers. Just **don't** use defines for these things in C++ (specifically it looks like it's in `MacTypes.h`. Oh well, google will know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing some

- includes (for the semantic actions)

  ```
  #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
  ```
- namespace aliases

  ```
  namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
  ```
- using statements / qualifiers

  ```
      using qi::_val;
      using qi::_1;
      using qi::_2;
  ```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5867c02d58dd123)**

Note also that the `[_val = _1]` is redundant (automatic attribute propagation achieves the same).

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
struct ExpressionGrammer : qi::grammar<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> addsub;

    ExpressionGrammer()
    : ExpressionGrammer::base_type(expression)
    {
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::_2;

        addsub = (expression >> '+' >> expression)[_val = _1 + _2];     
        expression = (addsub | qi::double_)[_val = _1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    ExpressionGrammer<char*> g;
}
```

Comment: That's it, with an additional requirement from your comment as well: MacTypes.h defines `Nil` and `nil` as `NULL` which is at the root of the 'Declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition errors', as Boost Fusion has a `struct nil;`. Although my cpp file does not include any headers apart from Boost, the Xcode setup from the Framework I'm using seems to automatically include MacTypes.h. It's fixed by adding `#undef nil` and `#undef Nil` before the Boost includes. Thanks!

Comment: And apparently I can't spell 'grammar'.

Comment: According to https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5010, the issue with the `nil` struct is fixed in Boost 1.55.

Comment: Although it is clearly not a boost issue. Having macros randomly replace tokens in your source file is recipe for sadness. I appreciate boost accomodating this one instance for a popular library, but really lobobjc/MacTypes.h should be fixed (like `windows.h` can now be used without define `min` and `max`)